# Three-way bulb's brightness levels are out of sequence

Tags: led

I have tried 2 3-way LED bulbs by GE.  The settings are 50w, 100w and 150w.  They have the same base configuration as incandescent 3-way bulbs (extra ring around center contact). When I turn it to the first click this is the lowest brightness (like a 50W).  Turning it to the second click it puts out about twice as much light (as it should).  Turning it to the third click, the brightness goes to slightly LESS than the second click level.

I bought the first bulb, had this experience and assumed it was faulty.  Bought a second bulb and had the same experience.  The third click is dimmer than the second.

I've tried the bulb in three different lamps that have a 3-way switch.  Same results in all of them.

Is this a flaw in the GE bulb or is there some other problem?

Answer (score 6):

17-Nov-15:  Received a response from GE Lighting:
This product (LED22A50/150) was designed to have the highest light setting in the middle position.

In other words, the order of the light settings is low(50), high(150) and medium(100).

This was done so that if you use the bulb in a single wattage socket it will light on the highest light setting.

Wonderful!  So it works in a single wattage socket AND doesn’t behave like a standard three-way bulb!